# What happens to the task that is initiated if the web api returns the response

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to implement a task in fire and forget manner.

Lets look at the below piece of code.

```
public IHttpActionResult Update(int id)
{
   var updatedResult = _updater.update(id);

   // fire and forget a task

   sendEmailToUser();

   return ok();

}

private async Task sendEmailToUser()
{
   var httpclient = new HttpClient();

   // assume the client is initiated with required url and other headers

  await httpclient.postasync("some url");

}
```

Given the above code, can i safely assume that whenever Update endpoint is called, sendEmailToUser task is triggered and will be run to completion ?

Comment: *"and will be run to completion"* - Does it matter?  People always conveniently ignore the second half of "fire and forget"... *forgetting*.  You can *assume* whatever result of the operation that you want.  But if you want to in any way *observe* or *confirm* the result of the operation, you can't *forget* it.  What you *can* do is perform a faster operation, such as writing to a message queue, and then returning control to the user.  Then some *other* process would conduct the intended operation and reliably observe its result.

Comment: my idea is to trigger another api that performs send email and don't want to wait until the email is sent. What i want to know is whether the back ground task run to completion even if the parent task is done.

Comment: @David: There's a difference between caring about the result of a task, and **knowing** that tasks (in general) will be done to completion. OP isn't asking about the outcome of any particular task, but rather whether .Net doesn't just outright kill the thread after returning a web response. That has nothing to do with the "forget" in fire and forget.

Answer (score 2):

No. You should almost never start any background threads in web application. HTTP is suppose to be stateless and the web server was designed with that in mind.

The server might be put into sleep state when there is no incoming request for a set period of time. During that time all the background execution will be halt including the one you had. It might and might not get resume when the next request comes in.

Or when IIS decides to recycle your App domain on a scheduled basis your thread will get killed too.

If you really need background tasks then do that using windows service or run it as a separate console application.

Comment: "The server might be put into sleep state when there is no incoming request for a set period of time. During that time all the background execution will be halt including the one you had. It might and might not get resume when the next request comes in."

Need more clarity on this statement.

You meant to say the background task will be alive as long as the parent is. Which means, when the parent task dies, after returning the OK response, the background task will be halted and there is no guarantee that the httpclient.postasync call would be made ?

Comment: @KiranR that is only one case of when the thread might get terminated. IIS app domain recycle will kill your thread too. And there are more cases which I can't remember. The general idea is to avoid background threads unless  you are ready to perform checks and cleanup when they got killed from time to time

Comment: Async processing isn't the opposite of stateless. The two concepts are unrelated. Stateless revolves around not retaining any knowledge **between subsequent** web requests.

Comment: @Flater If you look carefully at his code he doesn't want to await on the async request but instead fire it and forget it. async processing is 100% fine if it finishes before the request is returned which is part of what I mean with stateless

Answer (score 1):

Under normal conditions, it's reasonable to expect that the task will run to completion. It will go on independently.

Your biggest concerns, in this case, should be about the web API not being terminated, and the task not throwing an exception.

But if OP needs to be 100% sure, there are other safer ways to code that.

Comment: I don't know exactly why this was downvoted, but I would guess that the first line should be "no" followed by the second paragraph.

Comment: @Taegost: OP's question is `can i safely assume that whenever Update endpoint is called, sendEmailToUser task is triggered and will be run to completion ?` Matheus' response of "yes" is actually what he means, based on his elaboration that the task will continue.

Comment: That's right. I meant to say that, under normal conditions, it's reasonable to expect that the task will run to completion.
But if OP needs to be 100% sure, there are other safer ways to code that.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what is meant, which is why I didn't downvote it, but someone did, and I think it's because while this answer is not wrong, but as it's currently worded it also isn't correct based on the OPs additional qualifier of "run to completion".  I think if @MatheusLacerda includes the previous comment in the answer, it'll turn that downvote around

Comment: @Taegost, thanks for the input. Edited as you suggested.

Comment: Excellent, Looks great!